# deactivate a variable after use

Tags: java, encapsulation

Is there some annotation that can allow me to tell the java compiler that
a variable is not supposed to be used after the annotation? Thanks to
the autofill and copy paste features of modern IDEs, it is too easy introduce
bugs by mistyping variable names. Such annotations will help detect some of those bugs at compile time (or at typing time if one is using smart IDEs like netbeans/eclipse).
As an example, I have the following string processing pipeline:

```
String input = ....
String pass1 = op1 (input);
...
String pass2 = op2 (pass1);
...
String pass3 = op3 (pass1); // typo: pass1 should be pass2
...
return pass3;
```

If I could say something like `disable pass1` just after the line where `op2` is called, 
the typo in the line where `op3` is called will be detected as `pass1` would be out of scope as the result of the hypothetical `disable` annotation.

Comment: Just don't name variables that way. Or reuse the variables.

Comment: Where are `annotations` in your example?

Comment: `disable pass1` is the annotation I wish existed. The general format is `disable` followed by a variable name that is in scope.

Comment: If you're running into this problem, you're probably writing methods that are too long.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot deactivate variables in Java. As an alternative, reuse the variables, instead of creating new ones:

```
String input = ....
String currentPass = op1 (input);
...
currentPass = op2 (currentPass);
...
currentPass = op3 (currentPass);
...
return currentPass;
```

In theory, a sufficiently smart IDE could use [java annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) to throw a warning. However, that is a bad idea. The syntax would be ugly, and would tie you to a particular IDE. Additionally, there are no Java IDEs which implement that 'feature'.

Comment: @StephenC Java8 allows you to annotate type casts e.g. `(@Deactivate String) pass1;`.

Comment: Would that help here?

Comment: @StephenC An IDE could treat the statement `(@Deactivate String) pass1;` as equivalent to the hypothetical statement `disable pass1;` that the OP describes. I do not thing it is a good idea, but it is the closest the OP could come to the `disable` statement while maintaining source compatibility with standard Java code.

Comment: I'd change "not a good idea" to "is a seriously bad idea".  For a start, putting IDE specific annotations into your code is tying your source code and development process to one IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "deactivate" variables in the way that you describe / desire.

However, if you design the block structure appropriately, you can arrange that certain variables are out of scope; e.g.

```
String input = ....
{
   String pass1 = op1 (input);
   ...
}
String pass2 = op2 (pass1);  // compilation error ... pass1 is out of scope.
```

It is unclear whether this gives you sufficient control to achieve what you are really trying to do.  But if, not then I can't think of any alternatives that would work at compile time ...

---

Reusing the variables as described by @Joshua is another approach.  It avoids the problem rather than solving it directly.

Comment: Using block structure was my first thought and it might be sufficient in many cases. But it does not work in mine because consecutive blocks need to share a variable.

Comment: In that case, you are out of luck.

Comment: @Abhishek Put the shared variable in an outer scope, like `input` in this example.